# Finding how many times a capital letters precede a period

Tags: javascript

I need to count how many letters are capital that precede a period. So find each period and check the character before to see if it is capital.

Here is some code I threw together that I thought would do the job.

```
var s = 'Washington D.C. is a nice place.';
var counter = 0;
var totals = 0;
var n = s.indexOf(".",counter);
var times = s.split('.').length; 
var l = n;
while(counter != times){
  n = s.indexOf(".",l);
  if(s.substring(n-1,1) == s.substring(n-1,1).toUpperCase())
  totals++;
  counter++;
  l = n;
}
//totals should be 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var s = 'Washington D.C. is a nice place.';
var foo = s.match(/[A-Z]\./g,s);
console.log(foo.length);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pwfwt/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @j08691 is the most efficient, but in case you need one using fundamentals instead of RegExp (like for a school assignment or something) I'd go for something like this:

This version counts any capital letters *immediately* preceding a period.

```
var s = 'Washington D.C. is a nice place.';
var sLower = s.toLowerCase();
var i = 0, num = 0;
while(i < s.length - 1) {
    if(s[i] !== sLower[i] && s[i+1] == '.') {
        num++;
    }
    i++;
}
alert('Upper case: ' + num);
```

It's structurally similar to what you have, but quite a bit more efficient. Could also be modified to use a for loop instead of a while.

Wasn't entirely sure from your question which you were after, so this version counts all capital letters preceeding the first period in the string:

```
var s = 'Washington D.C. is a nice place.';
var sLower = s.toLowerCase();
var i = 0, num = 0;
while(i < s.length && s[i] != '.') {
    if(s[i] !== sLower[i]) {
        num++;
    }
    i++;
}
alert('Upper case: ' + num);
```

Comment: PS: You could shorthand this down to 2 or 3 lines of code, but would be an unreadable mess :)